# How to connect to an Oracle database on a on premise server remotely using Python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

How would you connect to an Oracle database on a on premise server remotelly using Python?

I've tried with the library cx_Oracle but I can't figure out how to connect to a database that's not on my local computer nor the cloud

Comment: If it's running on your machine, what's wrong with using `localhost` for the hostname? For a database in the cloud, you use whatever the relevant hostname is.

Comment: Use the IP address of the server or the relevant hostname.

Comment: If you're just starting out, then use the latest version of cx_Oracle, which is now called python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a). Then read the manual about [connecting](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html).  In particular check the section on connection strings.  (If you have to stay on the old cx_Oracle namespace, then read the equivalent section in the cx_Oracle manual). If you're getting an error, then update your question with detail.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the network and firewall allow connections, then I'd do:

```
python -m pip install oracledb
```

And then use a script like:

```
import getpass
import os

import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')

connection = oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql = """select systimestamp from dual"""
    for r in cursor.execute(sql):
        print(r)
```

The key thing is what to set the `PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING` environment variable to.  Start with ['Easy Connect'](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#easy-connect-syntax-for-connection-strings) syntax.  Find the hostname or IP address where the database is running (for example myhost.oracle.com).  Find the service name (not the old "SID") of the database (for example the service name might be 'orclpdb1').  There will also be a port that is being listened on (the default is 1521).  Then set the `PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING` environment variable to `myhost.oracle.com:1521/orclpdb1`.

There are other connection string syntaxes usable, as [shown in the manual](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings).

Comment: EZCONNECT syntax and using the SERVICE name like Chris says, is your recipe for success!

Comment: I was having trouble using oracledb, turned out the key thing was using the Easy Connect syntax for the PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING, as Christopher described.  Thanks!